# Is it possible to scrape the class itself using rvest?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I want to scrape the class itself from a website's HTML code.

The HTML code is

```
<div class="table width-100 pad-left-none pad-right-none margin-bottom-md">
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="bold font-12 uppercase lt-grey letter-spacing-1 td">Customer Service</div>
            <div class="rating-static-indv rating-50 margin-top-none td"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- REVIEW RATING - QUALITY OF WORK -->
        <div class="tr margin-bottom-md">
            <div class="bold font-12 uppercase lt-grey letter-spacing-1 td">Quality of Work</div>
            <div class="rating-static-indv rating-50 margin-top-none td"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- REVIEW RATING - FRIENDLINESS -->
        <div class="tr margin-bottom-md">
            <div class="bold font-12 uppercase lt-grey letter-spacing-1 td">Friendliness</div>
            <div class="rating-static-indv rating-50 margin-top-none td"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- REVIEW RATING - PRICING -->
        <div class="tr margin-bottom-md">
            <div class="bold font-12 uppercase lt-grey letter-spacing-1 td">Pricing</div>
            <div class="rating-static-indv rating-30 margin-top-none td"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- REVIEW RATING - EXPERIENCE -->
        <div class="tr margin-bottom-md">
            <div class="td bold font-12 uppercase lt-grey letter-spacing-1">Overall Experience</div>
            <div class="rating-static-indv rating-50 margin-top-none td"></div>
        </div>
```

From this, I only want to scrape all the classes itself which has "rating-static-indv rating-...".

I tried this

```
x  <- NULL
k1<-"https://www.dealerrater.com/dealer/Fox-Volkswagen-of-Rochester-Hills-review-5380/?filter=ONLY_POSITIVE#link"
url<-paste(k1) 
review <- read_html(url)
states<- cbind(review %>% html_nodes("div.table.width-100.pad-left-none pad-right-none.margin-bottom-md")%>% html_attr("class") )
x<- rbind(x, states)
```

But, this returns "table width-100 pad-left-none pad-right-none margin-bottom-md" class only. I want my required output like below:

```
rating-static-indv rating-50 margin-top-none td
rating-static-indv rating-50 margin-top-none td
rating-static-indv rating-50 margin-top-none td
rating-static-indv rating-30 margin-top-none td
rating-static-indv rating-50 margin-top-none td
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just selecting the "table" `<div>`. you need to actually select the `<div>` that has the attributes you want. Try

```
review %>% html_nodes("div.table div.rating-static-indv") %>% 
  html_attr('class')
```

Comment: Now I got it, I considered the table data also as a class name. Thank you.